# How does TestCafe, the open source tool, relate to DevExpress TestCafe, the $249.99 dollars per year application?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, devexpress, e2e-testing, testcafe

Do the two of them integrate somehow? The relation between the two is confusing and they have the same name. 
Can the $249.99 tool be used to run tests written using the open-source API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TestCafe first appeared as a paid, standalone tool. It had several features besides the test runner: the [Control Panel](https://testcafe.devexpress.com/Documentation/Using_TestCafe/Control_Panel/), a visual interface for creating, modifying and running your tests, and the [Visual Test Recorder](https://testcafe.devexpress.com/Documentation/Using_TestCafe/Visual_Test_Recorder/) for recording tests by pointing and clicking through the test scenario in the browser.

In 2015 we decided to release the TestCafe core as an open-source project. The last major paid version release (v15.1) was in summer 2015. After that, it switched to a maintenance-only mode. You can find the latest paid version at [https://testcafe.devexpress.com](https://testcafe.devexpress.com/).

We released the open-source TestCafe in late 2016. It has the same name but contains lots of new functionality and improvements:

- a new API and offers a new approach to writing tests;
- no UI to manage and run tests. You can run tests from the CLI or node.js module;
- it is more convenient to integrate into node.js development workflow;
- es6 support, flexible selectors and smart assertions, authentication features, etc.

You can learn more about the open-source version at https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe.

We have not abandoned our aspirations to create a competitive proprietary product. We plan to release a new commercial version called TestCafe Studio, based on the revised open-source TestCafe.

Comment: Can open-source TestCafe be used to automate ASPxGridView and other DX ASP.NET Web-Forms controls testing? Or did you cut off that functionality from the open-source version?

Comment: At DevExpress, we are using new TestCafe internally for all our web integration tests, so yes, it can test WebForms components

Comment: @RomanEremin are you using iternally the open sourced TestCafe version or the propriatory one? My principal question is whether the current open source TestCafe version can be used to test Web-Forms controls in say v16.2 of DX ASP.NET controls. PS. We have an active DX subscription.

Comment: Yes, open source TestCafe can test DX ASP.NET controls. Do you have any particular problem?

Comment: @RomanEremin Is Visual Test Recorder still present in the open source version of the TestCafe? I can't find it.PS. Add "@andrews" to your comments so that I may receive notification when you reply.

Comment: @andrews, Visual Test Recorder will be a part of commercial version.

Comment: @RomanEremin thanks for the reply. So with the open source version can I reference DX modules via  "@require :dx"; like it is done here: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T205215/how-to-create-a-test-for-a-master-detail-aspxgridview-using-testcafe-wrappers ?

Comment: @andrews, With the open source version, you run tests written with both the legacy API and the new one. But you can't mix them in one test, e.g. you can't use helper modules written with a legacy API in a test written with the new API.

Comment: @AlexanderMoskovkin we're a long time paid DX suite users. We do need to have some functional testing applied to pages using DX. Could we pls connect somehow to discuss the details of TestCafe? We may consider purchasing the commercial version if we have to.

Comment: @andrews Sure we can. Please contact me via my email alexander.moskovkin@devexpress.com